# Is it fine to install a node module, while the Expo CLI server is running?

Tags: reactjs, npm, expo

Is it okay to install a module using `npm install <package-name>` while the expo CLI server is still running? Can it break certain things? Is the installation affected in any way?
Does hot reload still work? Do newly installed modules immediately work without restarting the server?

I would like to know more about the background processes of Expo.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I tried installing the `react-navigation` while the server was active. I had the feeling this caused hot reloading to crash (for the former running instance), but I am not sure. I am now not confident enough to install modules again while the server is active, so I hope someone can answer me this.

Comment: Just to add to this in case anyone finds a fix. Every time I install a package and use it, I need to restart expo. If I don't, I get a package not found error. It's not really a problem, it gets resolved once I restart expo, but it really takes a toll on my productivity.